# MYSQL (Gente gostaria de um exemplo de como listar os serviços utilizados para um cliente qualquer x que tenha um cachorro com nome qualquer y)

Tags: mysql

olha não estou conseguindo fazer precisava de um exemplo.
so nao consigo fazer esta consulta
Listar os serviços utilizados para um cliente qualquer x que tenha um cachorro com nome qualquer y.

```
create database pet;
use pet;

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
cod_cliente int primary key auto_increment,
nome varchar(100) not null,
telefone int,
cpf varchar(14) not null unique,
cel varchar(15) not null,
endereco varchar(100)not null
);

CREATE TABLE ANIMAL(
cod_animal int primary key auto_increment,
nome_animal varchar(100) not null,
sexo SET('M','F'),
idade int,
raca varchar (50)not null,
data_cadastro datetime not null 
);

CREATE TABLE FUNCIONARIO(
cod_funcionario int primary key auto_increment,
nome_funcionario varchar(100) not null,
cpf varchar(14) not null unique,
sexo SET('M','F'),
especialidade varchar(30) DEFAULT'tosador',
cel varchar(15) not null,
endereco varchar(100)not null
);

CREATE TABLE SERVICO_ANIMAL(
cod_cliente int,
cod_animal int,
cod_funcionario int,
FOREIGN KEY(cod_animal) REFERENCES ANIMAL(cod_animal),
FOREIGN KEY(cod_funcionario) REFERENCES FUNCIONARIO(cod_funcionario),
FOREIGN KEY(cod_cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE(cod_cliente)
);

describe ;
INSERT INTO cliente(nome,telefone,cpf,cel,endereco) VALUES 
('roberto','32265849','78945622','999282127','rua andradas'),
('reginaldo','32228949','78989437','999282237','rua esmeralda'),
('ana paula','32547165','78254883','999456821','rua juca'),
('dagoberto','32123654','78854713','999126845','rua tereza'),
('roberto','22132547','78456927','99987594600','rua santana');

INSERT INTO animal(nome_animal,sexo,idade,raca,data_cadastro) VALUES 
('toby','F','5','poodle','2017-06-21'),
('neco','M','2','chow chow','2017-07-27'),
('nick','M','1','pastor','2017-10-27'),
('luqui','M','7','salsicha','2017-04-26'),
('chica','F','15','pinther','2017-10-17');

INSERT INTO funcionario(nome_funcionario,cpf,sexo,especialidade,cel,endereco) VALUES 
('roberta','0075555849','F','tosador','(52)355555569','rua dos andres'),
('roberto','0032265849','M','tosador','(51)548987469','rua gonalves'),
('joao','0032846569','M','tosador','(51)355956237','rua terneira'),
('reginaldo','0785465849','M','tosador','(51)355978946','rua assis'),
('reginaldinha','0756789789','M','tosador','(51)355546786','rua nogueira');
```

Answer (score 0):

Lá vai na ponta do dedo!

Aconselho alterar a estrutura de sua tabela para melhorar a perfomance e utilizar essa querie:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES C INNER JOIN ANIMAL A ON C.ID_CLIENTE = A.ID_CLIENTE 
INNER JOIN SERVICO_ANIMAL SA ON C.COD_CLIENTE = SA.COD_CLIENTE WHERE 
C.NOME = 'X' AND A.NOME_ANIMAL = 'Y';
```

Essa querie abaixo resolve o que quer na estrutura de tabelas que demonstrou ai em cima 
no entanto desaconselho essa estrutura porque deveria relacionar a tabela animal ao cliente (uma vez que o animal não existe sem um cliente. Correto?) com chave estrangeira, se futuramente precisar desenvolver outros módulos evita mais um inner join na queries o que dá grande diferença de performance.

Essa querie deve resolver o seu problema

```
SELECT * FROM SERVICO_ANIMAL SA INNER JOIN CLIENTES C ON SA.COD_CLIENTE = 
C.COD_CLIENTE AND C.NOME= 'X' INNER JOIN ANIMAL A ON 
SA.COD_CLIENTE = A.ID_ANIMAL AND A.NOME_ANIMAL = 'Y'
```

espero que isso seja útil! Abraços...